# How is MultiPV enabled in general?

Tags: engines, software

I looked at the "Description of the universal chess interface (UCI)" dated April  2006, and did not find a command or option that seemed to address how a GUI might enable MultiPV (I assume that PV stands for Position Value).  How does a GUI display MultiPV?

Background:  I hope there is a simple UCI command that enables MultiPV, so that I can issue the command on my BabasChess GUI.

Comment: PV stands for principal variations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"MultiPV" is the UCI option you are looking for.

> setoption name MultiPV value 10

Comment: It appears that this this setoption command must be sent before the UCI initialization command.